# Sorting would not work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have written a sorting function but it would not work. I have no idea where am i going wrong.The code below is suppose to sort picture on the basis of points

```
models.Picture.find().sort({points:-1}).all(function (err, pics){
if(err) {
    throw err;
}
pics.forEach(function(pic) {
    pictures.push(pic);
})
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling `run` and not `all`.  `all` invokes the [`$all`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all) operator which is an array matching operator.  As in:

```
models.Picture.find().sort({points:-1}).run(function (err, pics){
```